# Nautilus freezes with increasing amount of files in hard drive

Tags: nautilus, freeze, toshiba

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes)

Fresh installation of Ubuntu 12.10 was working very fine.
But after storing files in hard drive, **Nautilus** freezes all the time and have to *force quit* everytime I close window whereas other applications are just working fine.

Nautilus freezes much more when the disk storage is higher.

I'm using Toshiba Satellite C665.